# porting 'Vcl' component to 'Fmx' component

Tags: c++builder, firemonkey

I am porting a VCL component to FMX.

I already made the same functions as the previous VCL component. And I can install my new component and use it.

The problem is that my new component gains a new child component whenever I close and open the project again. Furthermore the number of these child components increases whenever I close and open the project.

[image]

So I made the component try to `delete` these object when created. But I could not solve this problem.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by setting the component's `stored` property to false.

```
Edit1->Stored = false;
```

I guess `Stored` was causing the duplicate components.  Changing `Stored` to `false` avoids that.

Comment: If your FMX component is creating its own `TEdit` child, you should be calling its `SetSubComponent(true)` method as well.